# How to update cells in the HTML Table row when change one column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have HTML Table on my page that's build dynamically. I make some of the cell editable. Also one cell contains calculated value based on two other cells in the same row. Here is the part of my table:

```
<tr class="mattersRow">
    <td class="editableCell hours">0.50</td>
    <td class="editableCell rate">170</td>
    <td class="editableCell amount">85.00</td>
</tr>
```

In jQuery I make my cells editable on double click:

```
        $('.editableCell').dblclick(function (e) {

            if ($(this).find('input').length) {
                return;
            }
            var input = $("<input type='text' class='form-control' />")
                              .val($(this).text());

            $(this).empty().append(input);

            $(this).find('input')
                   .focus()
                   .blur(function (e) {
                       $(this).parent('td').text(
                          $(this).val()
                       );
                   });
```

In term of trigger change event I extend var() method

```
$(function () {
            // Extending the val method so that the change event is triggered when value is changed using the val function.
            // caching the val function.
            var $valFn = $.fn.val;
            $.fn.extend({
                val: function () {
                    // Our custom val function calls the original val and then triggers the change event.
                    var valCatch = $valFn.apply(this, arguments);
                    if (arguments.length) {
                        $(this).change();
                    }
                    return valCatch;
                }
            });
        });
```

Now I trigger this event when value has change:

```
input.change(function () {
       $(this).closest('.amount').val($(this).closest('.hours').val() * $(this).parents('.rate').val()); 
// This is I can't get value of hours and rate cells...             
});
```

How to get value of rate and hours cells, calculate and put in amount cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after couple hours, I found a proper way=)
So, basically I don't need to trigger change event, I can recalculate values after replacement input back to text of `td` simply remember current row while input is active. jQuery code:

```
$(this).find('input')
     .focus()
     .blur(function (e) {
          var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // Remember row
          $(this).parent('td').text($(this).val());
          row.find('.amount').text(parseFloat(row.find('.rate').text()) * parseFloat(row.find('.hours').text())); // Calculate and put in the amount cell
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

You correctly started by converting the text to a value and editing it but in your final calculation you are trying to get the value of a text entry. Why not convert your cell entries to input fields which have values you can work with easily? E.g.

```
<td> <input type='text' class="editableCell hours" size='5' value='0.50'></td>
<td> <input type='text' class="editableCell rate" size='3' value='170'></td>
<td> <input type='text' class="editableCell amount" size='8' value='85.00'></td>
```

Comment: I had put this code twice accidentally. I'm inside this trigger. I need to recalculate immediately when user change some of the value (it can be rate, or it can be hours). The only thing that I need is how inside my trigger get those values?

Comment: Your input cells are of the class 'form-control' but from the html the classes you are looking for are applied to <td>s

Comment: I would suggest putting in a trap in the JQuery to prevent multiplication by zero if one of the fields hasn't been completed

Comment: I need this cells to be editable only on double click, otherwise it should be non editable. And I need refresh amount only if some value has changed. Class - 'form-control' is just css class, nothing to do with my values

Answer (score 0):

Closest function travels up the dom tree getting the parents of the element, similar to the parents function. Your rate and hour td elements are not parents so it will not find them. 
You could try getting the siblings of the inputs parents.

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".rate");
```

Also it looks like your removing your inputs on blur so you will then need to get the text instead of value.

```
$(this).parent().siblings(".rate").text();
```

Comment: Thanks for help, just found my own way.